# I have a Nikon D60 and two lenses: 70-300 and 18-135. Should I get a 50mm 1.8 prime?

Tags: lens, nikon, optics

I have a Nikon D60 and two lenses: a Tamron 70-300 mm f/4-5.6, and a Nikon 18-135 mm f/3.5-5.6.

I got all of these things really cheap, and now I want to buy a prime lens. I was thinking about a 50 mm or a 35 mm.

Can you help me choose the right one?

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of photos you wish to take with your new prime lens? What kinds of subjects? From what kinds of distances?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unclear. Whether or not you need a lens is dependent on your shooting style and scene needs. Please edit to add more info about this into your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A normal prime for the D60 would be a 35mm. The 50mm would be a good portrait lens. There are plenty of options out there for either, but I'd suggest looking for one that is at least an f1.8, to give yourself some ability to work in low light, since neither of your two zooms is very fast. You also want the lens to be able to take advantage of the D60's autofocus mechanism.

You will find a good list of compatible Nikon lenses for the D60 on [Ken Rockewell's excellent site](https://kenrockwell.com/nikon/compatibility-lens.htm#dslr). He indicates that those marked AF-S or AF-I will work. Lenses of other manufactures will also work, of course, if you check for compatibility.

If you look at reputable sources for used lenses, you can find many great values that should serve you well. But one last suggestion: good glass will improve your image quality and outlast your camera body. So think about something that you can take with you to your next camera, when you are done with the D60 and ready to try something new.

Comment: Consider the 35mm f1.8 DX G. Great lowlight lens.